# Power series to solve $y''-2xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Given the following ODE
$$y''-2xy=0$$
I have to solve it using power series. If
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$$
I got
$$a_{2}=0$$
and
$$a_{n+2}=\frac{2a_{n-1}}{(n+2)(n+1)},\quad\forall n\geq1$$
And since $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ are arbitrary, I evaluated
$$a_{3}=\frac{2}{3\cdot2}a_{0}$$
$$a_{4}=\frac{2}{4\cdot3}a_{1}$$
$$a_{5}=0$$
$$a_{6}=\frac{2\cdot2}{6\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2}a_{0}$$
$$a_{7}=\frac{2\cdot2}{7\cdot6\cdot4\cdot3}a_{1}$$
$$a_{8}=0$$
and so on. With these values, $y$ is such that
$$y(x)=a_{0}\left(1+\frac{2\cdot2}{6\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2}+\frac{2\cdot2\cdot2}{9\cdot8\cdot6\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2}+\ldots\right)+a_{1}\left(1+\frac{2\cdot2}{7\cdot6\cdot4\cdot3}+\frac{2\cdot2\cdot2}{10\cdot9\cdot7\cdot6\cdot4\cdot3}+\ldots\right)$$
is there some way to write it using some sum or formula? I thought about powers of 2 but the almost factorial in the dominators are quite hard to work with.

Comment: Hi, you missed powers of x, and to suggest for your answer, may be try completing factorials if it helps.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function